# Refreshing view attribute (specified in resources) after configuration change

Tags: android, android-resources, android-configchanges

I have a dimen specified in values/ and values-w600dp/ because I would like an icon to be wider on very wide screens.

values/

```
<dimen name="myIconWidth">32dp</dimen>
```

values-w600dp/

```
<dimen name="myIconWidth">48dp</dimen>
```

layout/

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="@dimen/myIconWidth" ...
```

However, I am currently manually handling the orientation change:

Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|..."
```

Therefore, the layout_width still uses the (potentially incorrect) old value after the orientation change.

How best to update the layout_width (presumably in the onSizeChanged() method)?

Answer (score 0):

because of use android:configChanges="orientation|..." if you use this attr then android never create new view for you so,you have to handle it in your onConfig method of activity 
i think you did it,but you have given name of layout file while in landscape mode or portrait   mode

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, that's true and that's pretty much what I said in the question. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: hi as per your question you did not create layout--w600 folder just create it put your layout file here because "values-w600dp/" always render during layout-w600

Comment: why would it "render" layout-w600dp but not values-600dp?

Comment: i think your need to check Qualifier name rules of android values-600dp never come it should be Version (API level) [for example : values-14] .

Comment: sorry, but that is not relevant to this discussion.